# is mult_add a real function? What does it do?

Tags: haskell

I have the following question given to me.

> Write a function form_number_back that takes a list of positive integers and forms a decimal number using the numbers in the list in reverse order.
>
> For example form_number_back [1, 2, 3, 4] should return the number 4321; 
>   form_number_back [ ] returns 0
>
> Use the function foldr and mult_add below to accomplish this `mult_add d s = d + 10*s`
>
> Note: foldr and foldr1 are two different functions. Try to use foldr1 instead of foldr in your definition and see if you get the same results with an empty list. Explain your results.

I cannot find anything on `mult_add`. I thought mabye it was the function name but she wants `form_number_back` as the function name. Which means `mult_add` is a Haskell function.

Can anyone explain to me what `mult_add` does? Is it even written right? Is `mult_add` another usermade function i'm supposed to use with my own code?

Edit 2

I tried putting in the function example to get its type.. 
so..
    form_number_back [1, 2, 3, 4] :: Num b => b -> [b] -> b

so my function looks like

```
form_number_back a = foldr(mult_add)
```

but is returning type of

```
form_number_back :: Num b => [t] -> b -> [b] -> b
```

Trying to figure out how to get rid of that `[t]`

Comment: `mult_add` is a helper function. Its definition is given as `mult_add d s = d + 10*s`. You should use that for `form_number_back`.

Comment: (It's says "enter it". Okay, I added the quotes. I wasn't sure if that text is in the original assignment or was added in formatting, but I think the quotes are relevant ;-)

Comment: If I gave you a string of digits, one at a time, starting with the "one's" digit and moving up, do you know how you would turn that into an actual number? So if I said "2 8 9 1" could you turn that into 1982? Do you know how you would do this conceptually (ignoring haskell for now)?

Comment: @ justin, My first thought would be to do some sort of reverse of the string and concat.. using the way the question wants it i'm kind of stumped. Foldr takes from the right side and reads backwards. Thus your reverse. Mult_add does something.. not sure what... So i'm attempting to do do something like... form_number_back [] = foldr(mult_add) But thats broken at the moment...

Comment: Here's a very small hint: `1982 = 2 * 1 + 8 * 10 + 9 * 100 + 1 * 1000 = 2 + 10 * (8 + 10 * (9 + 10 * (1 + 10 * (0))))`.

Comment: A different hint: write `mult_add` in a source file, load it, and ask ghci what the type of `foldr mult_add` is, `:t foldr mult_add`.

Comment: no matter how I try to pass in an list such as form_number_back ds = foldr(mult_add) I keep getting type of form_number_back :: Num b => t -> b -> [b] -> b I'm not sure what is causing the T.. i know its not mult_add.

Comment: @user1449653: `foldr` requires that you pass a function, initial value, and the list.

Comment: SO THATS HOW foldr WORKS THANK YOU!!!!!

Comment: Fun fact. In ghci, try entering `import Data.Char` and then `let f x = read (reverse (map intToDigit x)) :: [Int] -> Int` and then `f [1,2,3,4]`. Exercise: explain how this function works.

Comment: Who requires you to use those undescore names? I have nothing against it, but in Haskell _lower camelCase_ is very much the convention for multi-word value identifiers.

Answer (score 4):

Types are both more important and more informative in Haskell than in most other languages. When you don't understand Haskell, a good first step is to think about types. So let's do that. We'll fire up ghci and enter:

```
Prelude> let mult_add d s = d + 10 * s
```

And now ask for its type:

```
Prelude> :t mult_add
mult_add :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

That is, mult_add takes an `a` and another `a`, and returns an `a`, with the proviso that `a` is an instance of the `Num` class (so that you can add and multiply them).

You're asked to use `foldr` to write this function, so let's look at the type of that:

```
Prelude> :t foldr
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

That looks a bit intimidating, so let's break it down. The first part, `(a -> b -> b)` tells us that `foldr` needs a function of two variables, `a` and `b`. Well, we have one of those already - it's `mult_add`. So what happens if we feed in `mult_add` as the first argument to `foldr`?

```
Prelude> :t foldr mult_add
foldr mult_add :: Num b => b -> [b] -> b
```

Okay! We now have a function that takes a `b` and a `[b]` (a list of `b`s) and returns a `b`. The function you're trying to write needs to return `0` when it's given the empty list, so let's try feeding it the empty list, with a few different values for the remaining argument:

```
Prelude> foldr mult_add 10 []
10
Prelude> foldr mult_add 5 []
5
```

Hey, that's interesting. If we feed it the number `x` and the empty list, it just returns `x` (**Note:** this is always true for `foldr`. If we give it the initial value `x` and the empty list `[]`, it will return `x`, no matter what function we use in place of `mult_add`.)

So let's try feeding it `0` as the second argument:

```
Prelude> foldr mult_add 0 []
0
```

That seems to work. Now how about if we feed it the list `[1,2,3,4]` instead of the empty list?

```
Prelude> foldr mult_add 0 [1,2,3,4]
4321
```

Nice! So it seems to work. Now the question is, **why** does it work? The trick to understanding `foldr` is that `foldr f x xs` inserts the function `f` between every element of `xs`, and additionally puts  `x` at the end of the list, and collects everything from the right (that's why it's called a **right** fold). So, for example:

```
foldr f 0 [1,2,3] = 1 `f` (2 `f` (3 `f` 0))
```

where the backticks indicate that we're using the function in its infix form (so its first argument is the one on the left, and the second argument is the one on the right). In your example you have `f = mult_add`, which multiplies its second argument by 10 and adds it to the first argument:

```
d `mult_add` s = d + 10 * s
```

so you have

```
foldr mult_add 0 [1,2,3] = 1 `mult_add` (2 `mult_add` (3 `mult_add 0))
                         = 1 `mult_add` (2 `mult_add` 3)
                         = 1 `mult_add` 32
                         = 321
```

which does what you expect. To make sure you understand this, work out what would happen if you defined `mult_add` the other way around, i.e.

```
mult_add d s = 10 * d + s
```